# Friendly id & Globalize gem handling with locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, friendly-id, globalize

I have set up friendly id and globalize gem. I am also using 2 locales, `:es :en`

So I can create url like `/search/en/spain`.

On main page for :en, the url becomes `/search/en/spain` and for :es it becomes `/search/es/espana`. When I visit this page and try to change the language Friendly id gives error;

```
can't find record with friendly id: "spain"
```

Because the params should send `espana` instead of `spain`. How can I handle this on controller side? I have tried `Globalize.with_locale` but no luck.

I handle friendly id as

```
@country = Country.friendly.find(params[:country_id])
```

Route;

```
scope to: 'search#show' do
  get '/search/:country_id/', as: 'search_country'
end
```

Comment: I think you might be in need of one of these gems https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes or https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator

Comment: I think you might understood wrong. These are not the route names. Sorry my mistake I added my route. It fetches from database slug column